# Where is the user data (username, id, sessionid) when using CAS SSO jasig pycas?

Tags: python, single-sign-on, cas

When using python client with *CAS* from *jasig*, the following is sample codes:

```
import pycas
CAS_SERVER  = "https://casserver.mydomain"
SERVICE_URL = "http://webserver.mydomain/cgi-bin/webapp.py"
status, id, cookie = login(CAS_SERVER, SERVICE_URL)
```

The code supposed to work.  But no user data supported as parameter for `login(...)`. *Where* we support these kind of data? such as *username*, *userid*, *sessioonid*, *service_id*...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `pycas.login(CAS_SERVER, SERVICE_URL)`?